# What libraries are available for Java that parse IP header bytes?

Tags: java, tcp, udp, packet

On my project, we have been writing our own IP header parsing code for some time now. I'm starting to wonder if our time could be spent better elsewhere. A google search has not yielded much of use.

Basically, what I am looking for is a third party library that will be able to parse out all of the meaningful information out of a IP packet header stored in a byte array.

Someone told me that there was a Java Wireshark library out there that used JNI to wrap libpcap. Does anyone know of a pure Java solution? Commercial or open-source solutions both would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

On your libpcap question, look at the [WinPCap links page](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/links.htm) and you will find [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/)

Comment: You could also look at the related jNetStream as a pure Java solution, although it can't do packet capture. And the developer is now focusing on jNetPcap.